# How to create dropdown menu that appears based on answer from another dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I'm trying to create a page where you users have to make multiple selections that are based on each other. How do you create a form such that a specific type of dropdown menu #2 appears based on the user's selection in dropdown menu #1.

For example, lets say a user has to choose a "product category" and a "product subcategory". If a user chooses "bedding" from the first drop down menu, a second drop-down menu automatically appears with choices like "bed, mattress, pillow".

To further this example, lets say the user chose "electronics" instead of "bedding." Then the second-drop down menu would have choices like "tv, mp3 players, computers".

How would one go about doing something like that? Is it something you would do in HTML/CSS or some other form?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT - I'm using Django / Python to construct this website along with HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a combination of HTML and JavaScript **([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7Shsy/117/))**:

```
<select id="opts" onchange="showForm()">
    <option value="0">Select Option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<div id="f1" style="display:none">
    <form name="form1">
        <select id="opts" onchange="showForm()">
            <option value="0">Select Option</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1A</option>
            <option value="2">Option 1B</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="f2" style="display:none">
    <form name="form2">
        <select id="opts" onchange="showForm()">
            <option value="0">Select Option</option>
            <option value="1">Option 2A</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2B</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showForm() {
        var selopt = document.getElementById("opts").value;
        if (selopt == 1) {
            document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "none";
        }
        if (selopt == 2) {
            document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "none";
        }
        if (selopt == 0) {
            document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How would you write the above using external CSS? I know how to do it in HTML, but in the JS code, does one leave it in as shown or does it call the style sheet also?

Comment: @wordman I'm not really sure what you mean, can you link your code?

Comment: @amiregelz, I was referring to the above code and how JavaScript deals with CSS. Specifically, can `document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "block";` be done differently? It lookshard-coded, can it be done to call another element in a style sheet?

Answer (score 3):

Like this? Created a js fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/MeTQQ/

It grabs the value of the drop down box, and then if it matches the rule, it'll set the other drop-down box to show, if not, keeps that other drop-down box hidden.

Comment: Not a bad starting point +1, but he could probably use some more explanation.

Comment: Cheers for the input - added a brief description - upped.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use jQuery, you can use this test case:
http://jsfiddle.net/exXmJ/

The way I see it there are two ways to go. Delete the dropdown and exchange it for a new one, or hide/show two different dropdowns. Alexander covered the second method so I won't go into that.

Comment: Side note: I wouldn't use the example by Alexander exactly as is, mainly because it uses inline css. You should put the css in a style sheet to seperate design from markup. The actual approach is okay, though an event listener might be better than an onclick="" attribute.